# Delaying API calls between multiple parallel processes

Tags: c#, api, function-call, vonage

I'm working on adding SMS notifications to a C# web application. In a nutshell, a user logs into the interface, types a message, selects recipients, and saves. I'm utilizing Hangfire to spin up background jobs - those jobs handle the actual building and then the sending of the SMS messages out via the provider (currently Nexmo).

Nexmo, as well as most other SMS providers, have a throttle on their API which limits the ability to queue outbound messages to a rate of X/sec, with the rate varying based on your account level. For my testing purposes I'm limiting to 1/sec.

At present when my background process begins I'm keeping track of the amount of time that has passed between API calls and if it less than 1sec, I put the thread to sleep for the amount of time remaining. This seems to work fairly well, *however* the issue I'm running into is that there is the potential for multiple parallel background processes to be running simultaneously, such as when two users trigger SMS outbound messages to go out at the same time. There is another item of complexity wherein if you use 2 outbound numbers, your API limits effectively double (1 message/second from *each* number used). I'm ignoring that at present and simply delaying between all API calls.

I'm looking for any advice on how to circumvent this issue. My one idea is to decouple the processing of messages from the background job entirely - with the hangfire job simply building the messages and flagging them as queued for sending, and a separate single-threaded application that acts essentially as a watcher and sends out messages FIFO.

any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The throttling of API requests is going to be different depending on which country and number type you are using. Generally the limit is 30 API Requests per second per key - but that is subject to regional restrictions please see:

https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/203993598-What-is-the-Throughput-Limit-for-Outbound-SMS-

https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/sections/200622473-Country-Specific-Features-and-Restrictions

For example if you were using a US Long Virtual Number(LVN), as opposed to a short code or toll-free number, are capped at 1 message per LVN per second and 250 messages per day. If this is the restriction you're running up against you may want to consider the type of number you're using as US LVN is really not meant for P2P sms messages.

### Update:

You can set the configuration setting

```
"appSettings": {
    "Nexmo.Api.RequestsPerSecond": "30"
  }
```

to your appsettings.json - this will make the configuration set it's http client to use a ThrottlingMessageHandler - as any Nexmo API client leverages a singleton instance of configuration (and therefore it's http client) this will effectively stop you from sending more than the throttled number of of requests per second.

Comment: thanks for your response, those links are how I built v1 of the logic. What I'm really looking for are some recommendations on how to handle this type of scenario in a general sense, whether its Nexmo, SignalWire, Twilio, etc. A situation where I have N workers processes sending variable number of simultaneous requests that must be spaced out from one another, with visibility to the throttle amount that applies across workers. All I can come up with is  single-threaded watchdog-esque application processing the queue as it comes in.

Comment: @CaryonInferno amended my original response - there's a configuration setting you can set to throttle the number of allowed requests.

Comment: thanks! Apparently I don't have enough cred to upvote your answer but I appreciate it.

Comment: Hi @CaryonInferno - if you could accept the that would be wonderful as it might help the next person who has this question. thanks!